# put some audio files without taking too much data with android native

Tags: android

How do I put audio files into an android native application without taking too much data (about 50 songs for example, at least), like in "Don't tap the white tiles" ... I thought about converting the songs into MIDI but there is lot of losses in the sound ... Or, if someone knows how to handle those kind of application, please, help